# ParallelDo behaves unexpectedly (that is, against my expectations!)

Tags: parallelization

Here's an example of a Do loop that performs as expected. (I realize that the DO loop is not the optimum construct here but my real work has a much more complicated structure so I've reduced to a minimal example to show my problem.

```
loc = ConstantArray[1, 5];
Do[
  {
   loc[[j]] = Total[RandomReal[1.0, 3]];
   },
  {j, 1, 5}
  ];
loc

(*{0.939773, 1.56823, 1.21009, 1.01854, 1.7389}*)
```

I then try to execute the same code except I replace Do with ParallelDo:

```
Clear["`*"];
loc = ConstantArray[1, 5];
ParallelDo[
  {
   loc[[j]] = Total[RandomReal[1.0, 3]];
   },
  {j, 1, 5}
  ];
loc
(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}*)
```

So it seems that the loop is never executed. If for some reason the algorithm is not amenable to parallel processing, the documentation says ParallelDo reverts to Do.

```
$ProcessorCount
$Version
$VersionNumber
(*10
(*"13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)
13.3*)
```

I think I am missing something basic. Thanks for any help.

Comment: SetSharedVariable[loc]

Comment: Documentation for ParallelDo (Basic Examples and Possible Issues) describes the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Also be careful with randomization in parallel evironment. Remember that pseudo random number generators are deterministic. So you have to make sure that every thread gets his own random number generator with its own seed. I don't know how exactly this is done in _Mathematica_; I am just telling you that you should watch out for best practices.

Comment: Aha.  Thanks @1729taxi.  If you would like to offer as an answer I will accept.  II am still a little confused as to why at least one of the kernels does not provide a result in loc but your response is helpful.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! While not an issue in the MWE I constructed, your comments about synchronizing random number generators is insightful - and graciously worded! Much appreciated.